# Temporarily only allow network-access via (sshd-socks) Proxy

Tags: windows-7, ssh, proxy, firewall, blocking

I am alot on business trips using the hotel's hotspot.
I connect to my solaris-server using putty/ssh and establish a socks-proxy.
Using Chrome and Proxy Switchy, I surf via the sshd's socks-proxy.

Is there any possibility to temporarily block all other network-access bypassing the proxy?
I really dont want to appear any pop3/imap data on the public wifi when starting thunderbird my mistake...

Thanks

Comment: This is why you normally use IMAP with SSL enabled...

Comment: If you have your own server, why wouldn't you setup an VPN, so you can tunnel everything?

Comment: I use IMAP over TLS, but mentioned the unencrypted way as an example. I like the very lightwight proxy-approach. What is a recommended VPN-solution? OpenVPN?